# elasticsearch embedded in Node.js

Tags: node.js, testing, elasticsearch, mocking

I am new on developing in Node.js, I would like to know if there's a way to have ElasticSearch embedded in a Node.js application for testing purposes or if there's another way to test interaction with ElasticSearch without having an ElasticSearch running instance (mock ?)

Answer (score 4):

There are no existing mock libraries for Elasticsearch and Node at the moment. If you know exactly what queries you are going to be performing, you could use a mocking library to mock the entire ES client and assert simple behaviors.

What I'd recommend, however, is actually running ES in a development environment for testing. I find that mocking external services is a pretty tricky thing to do in general, and your tests will likely be much more robust / trustworthy if running against an actual instance of the server.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer @rdegges

Comment: There is a package for Node.js, but it has Elasticsearch v.2.4
https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-mock-js